# Crop bitmap issue

Tags: java, android

I'm using this code to crop an image:

```
Bitmap raw = ((BitmapDrawable)hWlp).getBitmap();
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) 
    context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
wallpaper = Bitmap.createBitmap(raw, width/2, 0, width, height);
```

My source image (**raw**) is 800x960 and the target image is 800x480 (screen size). So I don't understand why I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x + width must be <= bitmap.width()
```

if in my case **x + width** (480/2 + 480) is 720 and **bitmap.width()** is 960

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like that :

```
 public static  Bitmap cropAndScale (Bitmap source,int scale){
    int factor = source.getHeight() <= source.getWidth() ? source.getHeight(): source.getWidth();
    int longer = source.getHeight() >= source.getWidth() ? source.getHeight(): source.getWidth();
    int x = source.getHeight() >= source.getWidth() ?0:(longer-factor)/2;
    int y = source.getHeight() <= source.getWidth() ?0:(longer-factor)/2;
    source = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, factor, factor);
    source = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(source, scale, scale, false);
    return source;
}
```

This is example and you can change variables by displaymetrics

Comment: It will change aspect ratio of the image, but it does not crop it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this error only, if your app is in landscape orientation ;)
I think, in this case metrics.widthPixels can return 800px instead 480px.

Comment: I crop images that are bigger than screen size to fit them within a screen. So I don't think orientation plays some role. Am I right?

Comment: The bitmap should have at least 1200px (800 / 2 + 800) as width to not avoid problem with this screen size for both orientation. Imagine that you have to support different screen sizes and images. So you need a general solution, but it depends on the requirements.)